# Finding asymptotic expansion of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I have the integrals
$$
I(\alpha)=\int\limits_\alpha^\infty\sqrt{t^2-\alpha^2}\,\frac{t\:dt}{e^{t-x}+1},\qquad J(\alpha)=\int\limits_\alpha^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{t^2-\alpha^2}}\,\frac{t\:dt}{e^{t-x}+1}
$$
and want to expand them analytically up to 4-th order in the small parameter $\alpha$ (here $\alpha,x>0$). At $\alpha=0$ they reduce to [Fermi-Dirac integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_integral), at $\alpha\ll1$ they acquire, at least, quadratic corrections, as seen numerically.

[image]

I tried to make the change of variables $u=\sqrt{t^2-\alpha^2}$,
$$
I(\alpha)=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{u^2\:du}{e^{\sqrt{u^2+\alpha^2}-x}+1},\qquad J(\alpha)=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{du}{e^{\sqrt{u^2+\alpha^2}-x}+1}
$$
and expand the resulting integrands
$$
\frac1{e^{\sqrt{u^2+\alpha^2}-x}+1}=\frac1{e^{u-x}+1}-\frac{e^{u-x}}{2(e^{u-x}+1)^2}\frac{\alpha^2}{u}+(\ldots)\frac{\alpha^4}{u^3}+\ldots
$$
in powers of $\alpha$, but, unfortunately, these expansions contain negative powers of $u$, which make the integrals diverging on the lower limit.

**Is it possible to obtain analytically asymptotic expansions of such kind of integrals?**

Comment: The first thing I would have tried is just expanding $\sqrt{t^2-\alpha^2}=t \left( 1 - \frac{\alpha^2}{2 t^2} + ... \right)$.  I don't know whether the resulting integrals can be done analytically, but they will converge, since $e^{-t}$ goes to zero more quickly than $1/t^n$ for any $n$.  If the integrals cannot be done analytically as they are, it may be possible to write it as $\int_0^\infty - \int_0^\alpha$ and approximate the second integral.

Comment: The plots in terms of $\alpha$ don't really tell us all that much, since $\alpha$ only enters as $\alpha^2$. Could you make the same plots in terms of $\alpha^2$? I think that would give more of an indication if it's possible to expand in $\alpha^2$.

Comment: @sasquires: There's no help from a factor $\mathrm e^{-t}$, unfortunately. The denominator goes to a finite constant as $t\to0$. (Otherwise the OP's approach would work, too.)

Comment: In Mathematica using `AsymptoticIntegrate` function(only for 2 terms) for first integral only return:$I(\alpha )\approx -\frac{1}{2} \alpha ^2 \log \left(1+e^x\right)-2 \text{Li}_3\left(-e^x\right)$

Comment: @joriki Yeah, that was dumb of me.  I briefly forgot about whether the problem was at $\alpha$ or $\infty$.